# Полетел каталог товаров wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

Каталог товаров в магазине слетел каким то чудом и выдает что то вроде этого[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в чем может быть проблема ? Где искать информацию

Comment: Напишите более полный вопрос, видно, что у Вас слетела верстка, но что Вы делали до этого, ну или хотябы ссылка на страницу не предоставлена.

Comment: @NikPashchuk я нашел решение , не понимаю откуда но присвоились стили position:relative , top:20px; lefr - 96 px ; убрал и все заработало